# Web Scraping : Getting Specific Values in a Website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web, web-scraping

Hi I wanted to get some information of this website
http://www.greenbook.org/market-research-companies/united-states-of-america

I want to get all Company Name and Telephone number

At first I tried to get all  data (Just to try)

using this code

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.greenbook.org/market-research-companies/united-states-of-america');

foreach($html->find('h2') as $element){
  echo $element->innertext . '<br>'; 
}
?>
```

But its not working can anyone help me one this how can I get the list of the companies here

Comment: I'm wondering if that will be possible without cross-origin-access.

Comment: I don't see any H2 elements in the URL source.

Comment: Pradeep there is the title it self Marketing Research Firms in United States of America

Comment: It seems web scraping can't work with `greenbook.org`; perhaps the page is generated with javascript or something but simple dom returns a `cant find page`..

Comment: @vlzvl no i can get all the info after JavaScript disabled in my browser

Comment: @SolutionsResource you can get all the info if you use Curl and stripos ( there is a pattern in the source code of the file) which makes it more easy !

Comment: I also trid that Curl function but it didnt work I'LL send you my code

Comment: @AncientGeek can you send some codes on how to get the company names of this website?

Comment: So it seems the site checks for user agent :) `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` does the trick indeed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfectly working code:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

function get_curl_output($link)
{
    $channel = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070219');
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

    $output = curl_exec($channel);
    curl_close($channel);
    return $output;
}

$content = get_curl_output('http://www.greenbook.org/market-research-companies/united-states-of-america');

$article_count = substr_count($content, '<article class="article article-lrg ">');
$article_data = array();
$company_data = array();

function article_getter($content, $index = 0)
{
    $article_pos_1 = strpos($content, '<article class="article article-lrg ">', $index);
    $article_pos_2 = strpos($content, '</article>', $article_pos_1+38);
    $article_str = substr($content, $article_pos_1+38, ($article_pos_2-38)-$article_pos_1);

    return array($article_str, $article_pos_2);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $article_count; $i++)
{
    if ( $i === 0 )
    {
        $article_data[$i] = article_getter($content);
    }
    else
    {
        $article_data[$i] = article_getter($content, $article_data[$i - 1][1]);
    }       
}

function filter($article)
{
    $name_pos_1 = strpos($article, '<b>');
    $name_pos_2 = strpos($article, '</b>', $name_pos_1+3);
    $name = substr($article, $name_pos_1+3, ($name_pos_2-3)-$name_pos_1);

    $telephone_pos_1 = strpos($article, '<span class="strong">Telephone:</span>', $name_pos_2);
    $telephone_pos_2 = strpos($article, '&nbsp;<span', $telephone_pos_1+38);
    $telephone = substr($article, $telephone_pos_1+38, ($telephone_pos_2-38)-$telephone_pos_1);
    $telephone = trim($telephone);

    return array($name, $telephone);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($article_data); $i++)
{ 
    $company_data[$i] = filter($article_data[$i][0]);
}

var_dump($company_data); //do whatever you want this array

?>
```

Comment: Do I need to use mozilla as my browser when doing this?

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\try\index.php on line 15

Comment: ei I got another problem

Comment: @SolutionsResource what problem ?

Comment: I need to get first the url then from that url I want to get the Company Name, Tel No, Email address and Contact person

Comment: I need to get all the Company's Url then get those details

Comment: @SolutionsResource you can get all the information just by modifying the given code

Comment: heres the url of my stactoverflow problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058715/web-scrapping-i-need-to-scrape-the-url-of-each-company

Comment: how I'll be getting since I need first to get the URL of each company and then enter to that url then GET ALL REQUIRED DATAS

Comment: Its a lil different and lil bit complex

Comment: Can you help me on this